# automate the creation of video of adobe premiere projects programmatically

Tags: java, c#, c, video, adobe-premiere

I created about 10 different projects in adobe premiere to create video sequences of 4 images with an audio in the background and the text on the images. The duration of the clip is 30 seconds. The problem is that I have to create more than 1,000 videos of different image sequences. I thought about creating a script in C or Java or any other programming language to automate this: in practice the script should copy the images to a folder start the rendering and when finished go to the next slide. I found nothing. Someone knows how to help?

Comment: On which language exactly?

Comment: With any language . the import is that I find the way! you have any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to consider using an entirely commandline-based process instead of trying to use Adobe Premiere.  This would allow it to be easily scripted.

FFMpeg is a commandline tool allows you to create a video from a sequence of images -- one image for for each frame of the video.  You can also mix-in your audio file with FFMpeg.  The hardest step will be generating images that have the proper text superimposed.

For more info on using FFMpeg you can start with an example like this:

https://lukecyca.com/2013/stop-motion-with-ffmpeg.html